# Search and replace multiple words with notepad++ (the text uses pipe to separate words)

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I have a file with thousands of lines and I need to find two terms that will always be on the same line, but there will be several lines of it in this file.

First, the file itself uses pipe | to separate data, like this:

`|C485|01|2,50||0,0000|||0,00|1052|62103|`

What I need to find is the lines that contains:

`|C481|01| and |0,0000|`

and replace the first word to:

`|C481|04|`

I found an answer to this question but when I chose to do the following, it did not work.

Using regular expression:
`(|C481|01|)|(|0,0000|)`

and

`|C481|01|.*|0,0000|`

I don't know much of regular expression, how can I find the two terms that use `|` ?

Comment: Why can't you just do one replace, and then the other, with an exact string match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is a regex special char, you have to escape it using `\|`.

In your case, replacing `\|C485\|01\|(.*\|0,0000\|)` by `|C481|04|$1` should suit your needs.